# Быстрая замена неправильной зависимости в Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

При создании переменных иногда случаются неправильные подключения зависимостей. К примеру, я хочу создать лист и вместо java.util.List подключается java.awt.List, так как в классе до этого уже использовались другие объекты этого пакета.
Если ли способ быстро разрешить неправильные зависимости, кроме как лезть в импорты, вручную удалять и заново все импортировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не однокнопочное но все же решение:

Поставьте курсор в конец объявления типа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нажмите `Ctrl+Space`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выберите необходимы тип и нажмите `enter`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тьфу. А я alt+enter жму, надеясь, что оно подскажет мне как исправить. Именно то что я искал

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko тоже мучался с этим раньше =)